# Question regarding matrix satisfying $A^8=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, matrix-equations, minimal-polynomials

> Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ real matrix satisfying $A^8 = I$. Which of the following is true?
>
> 1. Minimal polynomial of $A$ is of degree $3$
> 2. Minimal polynomial of $A$ is of degree $2$
> 3. $A = I$ or $A = -I$
> 4. There are uncountably many such $A$

My thoughts: the minimal polynomial divides $(x^4-1)(x^4+1)$ and is itself of degree $\leq 3$, so it can be of degree $2$ or $3$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Check the new edit

Comment: My guess is option 1,2,3 are all false. But what about 4?

Comment: Note that for any matrix satisfying $A^8=I$, if $B$ is any invertible matrix, then $C=B^{-1}AB$ also satisfies $C^8=I$. Then, if you can show one solution of $A^8=I$ that is not a multiple of the identity, you will get a way to construct uncountably many solutions.

Comment: @conditionalMethod: what if $B^{-1}AB$, as $B$ ranges over all invertible matrices, produces only two results? Sure, that doesn't happen --- except maybe for matrices with entries in $F_2$, the field of two elements; I haven't checked --- but there's no a priori reason to assume that it doesn't.

Comment: @JohnHughes Read my whole comment, and study it. Also read the question, specially the part that says 'real matrix'.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not technically an answer, but more of a longer comment**

Like you said, the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^8 - 1$. Observe that $$x^8-1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1). $$

Moreover, you can further decompose $$x^4 + 1 = (x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1), $$ and the polynomials on the RHS are irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thus, if $A$ has only rational elements, then the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$. However, the minimal polynomial of $A$ cannot be $x^2+1$, because, if $A^2 = -I$, then $A$ would be an $n \times n$ square matrix, with $n$ an even number (look at the Jordan normal form $J$ of $A$; you would have that $J^2 = -I$). So the minimal polynomial is either $x-1, x+1, (x-1)(x+1), (x-1)(x^2+1)$ or $(x+1)(x^2+1)$, and I believe all of them are possible.

However, if $A$ has real elements, the minimal polynomial can also contain factors of $x^4+1$ (but not $x^4+1$ itself, like you observed).

However, what I said technically implies that 1), 2) and 3) are false and that 4) is true (you can also see the comments).

Answer (score 1):

1. False because $I$ fulfills the relation
2. False because $I$ fulfills the relation
3. False becuase a $180^\circ$ rotation about the $z$-axis fulfills the relation
   other matrices as well, of course, but that's not needed.